ZAP causes CORS errors
When browsing an application through ZAP, some services respond with CORS errors or stop working correctly.
How can I correctly configure ZAP so that ZAP is not the origin but the application?
I have tried starting the browser from ZAP and the error continues. This doesn't happen if I access the app directly or through Burp Suite Community

Do you have the ZAP HUD enabled?
If so disable it.

HUD is disabled.
The access-control-allow-origin header in the response is set to just one domain
https://xxxxxxxxxxxx.com

Do you have any scripts enabled?
Did you launch the browser from ZAP?
If not, did you import and trust the ZAP root CA cert?
By default ZAP should not be changing anything that would cause CORS errors.

Also, we do have a ZAP User Group, which will not close questions like these :)
https://groups.google.com/group/zaproxy-users
